# Getting blank page in Android WebViewClient

Tags: android, twitter, webview, webviewclient

I am trying open twitter link : http://mobile.twitter.com/pawan_rathore88
in my activity. If I set WebViewClient to webview I am getting blank page.
But when I load url without setting any webviewclient, it loads page properly.
Does anyone have idea what can be a problem. Following is my code snippet.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//if I comment the following line then webpage loads properly in default Android browser.
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                 Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    Log.v(tag, "url :" + url);
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
        }
 });
    webview.loadUrl("http://mobile.twitter.com/pawan_rathore88");
```

Thanks,
Pawan

Comment: What do you mean a "blank" page. Do you mean an error saying it can't load the page?

Comment: Nope, just showing white page and nothing on it.

Comment: well the link works, interesting... Try just writing an application to just load the webpage and see if it works. something may be conflicting with it.

Comment: That I have already written, if I don't set WebViewClient, And simply loads url then it works like charm.

Comment: interesting is that your solution then?

Comment: @JoxTraex If you know answer, then post it here. That all I want to say.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6917/discussion-between-joxtraex-and-pawan)

Answer (score 1):

After tweaking the code around, it seems to be a user agent problem, seems that changing it to a desktop useragent fixes this problem :

```
  WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        web.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; " +
            "U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_3; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.16 (KHTML, " +
            "like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.16");

        String url = "http://mobile.twitter.com/pawan_rathore88";
        web.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Sorry, but its loading desktop webpages. Not that are for Mobile Devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with twitter at the moment and fails in all web kit mobile browsers.

Comment: the android browser extends the base functionality that is WebKit. Stop assuming so much Pawan, do some research.

Answer (score 0):

That is exact my problem too. Load Desktop version very good but not mobile version. If running on default browser, then Mobile version normally run. I think the problem is not well perform user string agent. But cannot find it out now.